# How to add the Color code for the Array values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have Sorted the array as Ascending order, In that array have some values, Some of the values are repeated, In that case I want add the color code for the Same values in the Array.

```
$level2 = array(
array ("marketMakerId" =>'CSTI',  "bid" => 0.0006,  "bidSize" => 4000000 ),
array ("marketMakerId" =>'GTSM',  "bid" => 0.0006,  "bidSize" => 650000 ),
array ("marketMakerId" =>'NITE',  "bid" => 0.0005,  "bidSize" => 10000 ),
array ("marketMakerId" =>'NITE',  "bid" => 0.0005,  "bidSize" => 10000 ),
array ("marketMakerId" =>'MAXM',  "bid" => 0.0001,  "bidSize" => 10000 ),
array ("marketMakerId" =>'MAXM',  "bid" => 0.0002,  "bidSize" => 20000 ),
array ("marketMakerId" =>'MAXM',  "bid" => 0.0003,  "bidSize" => 20000 ),
array ("marketMakerId" =>'MAXM',  "bid" => 0.0004,  "bidSize" => 40000 ),
array ("marketMakerId" =>'MAXM',  "bid" => 0.0078,  "bidSize" => 40000 ),
array ("marketMakerId" =>'MAXM',  "bid" => 0.0074,  "bidSize" => 40000 )
```

);

See the above array "bid" value 0.0006 in twice in the List, Now I want To add the color code the each row of array from the color code array, I have an another array Color code array, If reached the last color "Olive", The same color will be applied for all the remaining bid values

```
$color = array("red", "green", "Yellow",'brown','olive');
```

Now I want excepted output as below like this

```
$level2_output = array(
array ("marketMakerId" =>'CSTI',  "bid" => 0.0006,  "bidSize" => 4000000, 'color'=>'red' ),
array ("marketMakerId" =>'GTSM',  "bid" => 0.0006,  "bidSize" => 650000, 'color'=>'red' ),
array ("marketMakerId" =>'NITE',  "bid" => 0.0005,  "bidSize" => 10000 , 'color'=>'green'),
array ("marketMakerId" =>'NITE',  "bid" => 0.0005,  "bidSize" => 10000 , 'color'=>'green'),
array ("marketMakerId" =>'MAXM',  "bid" => 0.0001,  "bidSize" => 10000, 'color'=>'Yellow' ),
array ("marketMakerId" =>'MAXM',  "bid" => 0.0002,  "bidSize" => 20000 , 'color'=>'brown'),
array ("marketMakerId" =>'MAXM',  "bid" => 0.0003,  "bidSize" => 20000 , 'color'=>'olive'),
array ("marketMakerId" =>'MAXM',  "bid" => 0.0004,  "bidSize" => 40000, 'color'=>'olive' ),
array ("marketMakerId" =>'MAXM',  "bid" => 0.0078,  "bidSize" => 40000 , 'color'=>'olive'),
array ("marketMakerId" =>'MAXM',  "bid" => 0.0074,  "bidSize" => 40000 , 'color'=>'olive')
```

);

If the same bid value same color applied, If different Bid value then different color applied, See the The output array you can understand this,

Please help us

I have tried like this, Also this part is huge code, I post the what i am tried code only

```
array_multisort($value_bid, SORT_NUMERIC,SORT_DESC, $qty_bid,SORT_NUMERIC, SORT_DESC, $bid_level2);
// Obtain a Bid list of columns with sorting desc Ends

$colorMap[0] = 'red';
$colorMap[1] = 'green';
$colorMap[2] = 'Yellow';
$colorMap[3] = 'brown';

$keys   = array_keys($count_bid);
rsort($keys);
//print_r($keys);
$array3_bid = array();
$j=0;
for($i=0;$i<count($keys);$i++)
{
    if(!empty($colorMap[$j]))
    {
        $array3_bid[$keys[$i]] = $colorMap[$j];
        $j++;
    } else {
        $j=0;
        $array3_bid[$keys[$i]] = $colorMap[$j];
        $j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to add the code showing what you've already tried?

Comment: Please add the effort you have tried so far

Comment: Also what happen if  `$level2`  array size become 10 and each have different bid value, how you gonna assign them color?

Comment: @Martin I can't post answer right?

Comment: Color is maximum 5 color Only, If more bid value color code is repeatly assign the bids

Comment: @DrakulaPredator You can post an answer if you want, it's entirely up to you!

Comment: @Marttin If color reaches 5th colors, The 5th color only will continue for the renaming bid values, color should not be first color again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an associative array with the bid => color and loop the main array and add the color to the subarray.

```
$bids = array_unique(array_column($level2, 'bid'));
$bids = array_combine($bids, array_slice($color,0,count($bids)));

/*
$bids are now:
array(3) {
  ["0.0006"]=>
  string(3) "red"
  ["0.0005"]=>
  string(5) "green"
  ["0.0001"]=>
  string(6) "Yellow"
}
*/

foreach($level2 as &$sub){
    $sub["color"] = $bids[(string)$sub['bid']];
}

var_dump($level2);
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["marketMakerId"]=>
    string(4) "CSTI"
    ["bid"]=>
    float(0.0006)
    ["bidSize"]=>
    int(4000000)
    ["color"]=>
    string(3) "red"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["marketMakerId"]=>
    string(4) "GTSM"
    ["bid"]=>
    float(0.0006)
    ["bidSize"]=>
    int(650000)
    ["color"]=>
    string(3) "red"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["marketMakerId"]=>
    string(4) "NITE"
    ["bid"]=>
    float(0.0005)
    ["bidSize"]=>
    int(10000)
    ["color"]=>
    string(5) "green"
  }
  [3]=>
  &array(4) {
    ["marketMakerId"]=>
    string(4) "MAXM"
    ["bid"]=>
    float(0.0001)
    ["bidSize"]=>
    int(10000)
    ["color"]=>
    string(6) "Yellow"
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/UcdSi

---

In comments OP expresses he wants to loop the colors if it exceeds the 5 colors.
I create a new array with colors of the length needed by merging an array_fill of $color.

```
$color = array("red", "green", "Yellow",'brown','olive');


$bids = array_unique(array_column($level2, 'bid'));
$color = call_user_func_array('array_merge',array_fill(0,(count($bids)/5)+1,$color));
// $color = array("red", "green", "Yellow",'brown','olive',"red", "green", "Yellow",'brown','olive',"red", "green", "Yellow",'brown','olive');


$bids = array_combine($bids, array_slice($color,0,count($bids)));

foreach($level2 as &$sub){
    $sub["color"] = $bids[(string)$sub['bid']];
}

var_dump($level2);
```

See example of looping colors:
https://3v4l.org/DddeP

Comment: this one good too. I am also trying to do something like this only.+1

Comment: Its working fine, But Also i need to like this " If color reaches 5th colors, The 5th color only will continue for the renaming bid values, color should not be first color again "

Answer (score 1):

You can use foreach and do the things with some conditions as below,

```
$i     = 0;
foreach ($level2 as $k => &$v) {
    if (empty($bid)) {
        $bid = $v['bid'];
    } else if ($bid != $v['bid']) {
        $bid = $v['bid'];
        $i++;
    }
    // checking if $i > count of color then reset to 0
    if (($i + 1) > count($color)) {
        $i = 0;
    }
    $v['color'] = $color[$i];
}
print_r($level2);die;
```

I am resetting colors if it reached to last color.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/kfBNe).

Answer (score 1):

This just keeps a map of the bids against the color for that bid.  I use the bid as the key (I convert it to a string) and check if it is already set, if it isn't it adds the next color according to the count already used...

```
$level2 = array(
    array ("marketMakerId" =>'CSTI',  "bid" => 0.0006,  "bidSize" => 4000000 ),
    array ("marketMakerId" =>'NITE',  "bid" => 0.0005,  "bidSize" => 10000 ),
    array ("marketMakerId" =>'MAXM',  "bid" => 0.0001,  "bidSize" => 10000 ),
    array ("marketMakerId" =>'GTSM',  "bid" => 0.0006,  "bidSize" => 650000 )

);
$color = array("red", "green", "Yellow",'brown','olive');

$map = array();
foreach ( $level2 as &$element ) {
    $bid = (string)$element['bid'];
    if ( !isset($map[$bid]) ) {
        $map[$bid] = $color[count($map)%5];
    }
    $element['color'] = $map[$bid];
}

print_r($level2);
```

which gives (with just some test data)...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [marketMakerId] => CSTI
            [bid] => 0.0006
            [bidSize] => 4000000
            [color] => red
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [marketMakerId] => NITE
            [bid] => 0.0005
            [bidSize] => 10000
            [color] => green
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [marketMakerId] => MAXM
            [bid] => 0.0001
            [bidSize] => 10000
            [color] => Yellow
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [marketMakerId] => GTSM
            [bid] => 0.0006
            [bidSize] => 650000
            [color] => red
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [marketMakerId] => GTSM
            [bid] => 0.0002
            [bidSize] => 650000
            [color] => brown
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [marketMakerId] => GTSM
            [bid] => 0.0004
            [bidSize] => 650000
            [color] => olive
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [marketMakerId] => GTSM
            [bid] => 0.0003
            [bidSize] => 650000
            [color] => red
        )

)
```

Comment: Just one question, your input array is wrong as OP has already sorted it by bid, does it really need to I means, hope I am clear. I want to know what if array ends and color length reaches?

Comment: Note that OP wants to repeatedly assign colors if there are more than 5 bids

Comment: @DrakulaPredator Nigel just want to show his code works on an unsorted array

Comment: (Sorry just been shopping)... I've fixed the color re-use - just change the line to `count($map)%5` from `count($map)`.

Answer (score 0):

With this code you provided, note that if your array grows bigger than 4 items, multiple items will have the same color code, regardless of not having the same bid:

```
else {
        $j=0; //resetting the iteration token here results in multiple bid having the same color
        $array3_bid[$keys[$i]] = $colorMap[$j];
        $j++;
    }
```

But if that's not the problem, a solution would be to have another array which tracks the added color:

```
$mappedBidAndColor = new Array();//note this variable
if(!empty($colorMap[$j])) {
    //Check if the bid has been coloured 
    if (array_key_exists($mappedBidAndColor[$array3_bid[$keys[$i]]])) {
        //Pull the color and use it instead of assigning a new color
        $array3_bid[$keys[$i]] = $mappedBidAndColor[$array3_bid[$keys[$i]]];
    }
    else {
        $array3_bid[$keys[$i]] = $colorMap[$j];
        $mappedBidAndColor[$array3_bid[$keys[$i]]] = $colorMap[$i];//store the bid and the assigned color for future reference
        $j++;
    }
}
```

Edit the variables to fit your code, as I was not able to trace all your variables. But this will give you the idea you need.